# Objective-C, iOS: Getting images posted by follows on Instagram

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, mobile, instagram

I am getting avatar pictures from Instagram follows of the logged in user using this line of Objective-C code:

```
NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?count=-1&access_token=%@", self.accessToken];
```

Where `accessToken` designates the Instagram's access token of the logged in user.

If I now want to get the recently posted images from a subset of my follows, is there a way to query directly Instagram's backend to gain in efficiency?

Otherwise, how do I get all the images recently posted by my follows to then implement a query based on a subset of selected follows?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

maybe what you mean is getting your feed
you can use this code url to get the your feed

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

if you want the get recent post from your following member. you can use this code url

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/FOLLOWING-ID/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

you can get FOLLOWING-ID from ID that you get from user-id

maybe it can help you and other people.